# TypeScript inconsistency - why does compiler allow object property value assignment but no method return value assignment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am developing an Angular project using jQuery and noticed a strange anomaly. Look at the below TypeScript code from an Angular component class:

```
let foo :any | undefined = window.innerWidth * 0.26; // first line has no error
let bar :any | undefined = $(window).width() * 0.26; // second line has an error
```

The second line returns a compiler error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`. Let us assume that there is such a case and the compiler is right, when the `window` object was somehow not initialized and look at this code;

```
let asd :number = window.innerWidth * 0.26; // third line also has no error
```

In this case, there can be two errors (see [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/JS//js_typeof.asp) for reference);

1. `window` object has no `innerWidth` property defined, so `asd` will receive `undefined` as value, which is not of `number` type, so the compiler should throw `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)` error or the `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` error
2. `window` object was not instantiated, in which case it's type is `null`, so `asd` will receive no value and the program will return with `ReferenceError`.

For proof of concept, see this snapshot  from [w3schools' TryIt](https://www.w3schools.com/JS//tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_typeof_all) editor;

[image: PoC]

**So, my question is: why does the TypeScript compiler show error for the value assignment with jQuery method (first line), but no compiler error using the native JS object property approach (second and third line)?**

Comment: I've answered your question without trying it out on my computer. Do you use an outdated version of jQuery? I can't reproduce your problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAEjgMyhEcDkArAjgVwFMoBPTAbgFgAoGgG0PgCMBDKALjgDt8Qni4AHzj4uAE0LJgXQmLgBeRAAoA7tLEQVASgB0asTAAWSreSA

Comment: @jabaa Thanks for pointing this out, I checked the link, and tried to reproduce the code, and I too received no error. Then I checked my original code and saw, that there was an additional multiplication which I did not include in my question. The original code was let bar :any | undefined = $(window).width() * 0.26; - I've corrected my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of

```
$(window).width()
```

is

```
number | undefined
```

The multiplication

```
$(window).width() * 0.26
```

is only allowed for two numbers. You have to handle the case for `undefined`.  I would use a temporary variable and the conditional ternary operator:

```
const width = $(window).width();
let bar :any | undefined = width ? width * 0.26 : undefined;
```

The other lines don't cause an error because

```
window.innerWidth
```

has type

```
number
```

Comment: Yes, but why is window surely defined, while $(window) is possibly undefined? The former is the object, the latter is a selector aiming the object.

Comment: @Viktor `$` is a third-party function. There has to be a typing for this function. That's how the typing is defined. [Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery) is the typing.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to rework your answer in order to further analyse my updated question!